# Can others see if a YouTube video's monetisation is redirected off the uploader to the copyright claimer?

Tags: youtube

I think if someone besides the video uploader claims copyright for the video, then YouTube redirects ad monetisation to the copyright claimant. Is there a way for other viewers to know if this redirection has happened or not?

Answer (score -1):

I hope I understand correctly, but vidIQ, a Google Chrome Extension used to give estimates. I'm sure someone has come up with other ways also. I'm not aware of those, plus, the  numbers were way off...at least in my case.

Comment: How does this answer the question?